# mysql order by views then order these result by id desc

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i want to `order by views desc` then by `id desc`
i've tried

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC , `views` DESC
```

and

```
ORDER BY `views ` DESC , `id` DESC
```

it did not gave me the result i need

i want to get the most recent news by views

```
table news
id int(11)|views int(11)
```

any help please

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: Please take into account the comment of *juergen d* above. In addition, as a side note, *I* don't *like* using `id` to order things. Can't you add some kind of date or timestamp to your data? But maybe I am wrong with that...

Answer (score 1):

Then put the variables in the right order in the clause:

```
ORDER BY `views` DESC, `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

then use the order views first and then id.

try this

```
   ORDER BY  `views` DESC ,`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax is usually ORDER BY id, views  DESC